# Unable to install 'Velocyto.R' from Github

Tags: r, devtools, rtools

I am a beginner in R 
trying to analyze my scRNA-seq data with velocyto.R in R studio.
Following velocyto tutorial, I tried installing velocyto.R as below:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("velocyto-team/velocyto.R")
```

But, an error pops up:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'velocyto.R'

removing 'C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/velocyto.R'
Error: Failed to install 'velocyto.R' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpukpRFl/file37346a812b86/velocyto.R_0.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Is there anyone to face the same problem described above and succeed in resolving it after all?
I desperately need helps!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Rtools installed? Does `install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source")` run successfully on your system?

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your kind comment. But yea.. I've Rtools installed and install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source") works good on my system. Is there another way I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error log says `C:/...`, you probably use Windows. According to velocyto's [README](https://github.com/velocyto-team/velocyto.R) it seems that this package runs only on **unix-flavored systems** with `C++11`, `Open MP`, `boost`, `igraph` and `hdf5c++` libraries.

This can be the problem: read the velocyto's GitHub issue [#40](https://github.com/velocyto-team/velocyto.R/issues/40), maybe you'll need to run this under WSL...?

Comment: Ah, I missed that point... Thanks! Let me try to run velocyto under WSL.